# My iteration resets to 0 when it's in a condition

Tags: c

Problem :
Write a program that reads the natural numbers from the keyboard until it meets 0. Count how many of the read numbers are perfect numbers.

```
Expected:

Input   Result
6 28 0  there are 2 perfect numbers
28 496 0 there are 2 perfect numbers
```

The J index inside the second for, acts normally when I print it out, but inside the modulus condition, it outputs 0?

The code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[100], perfect = 0;
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &array[i]);
        if ( array[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if ( array[i] == 0 ){
            break;
        } else {
            int perf = 0;
             for ( j = 0; j < array[i]; j++) {
                printf("%i\n", j);
                    if ( j % array[i] == 0) {
                        perf += j;
                    }
            }
            if (perf == array[i]) {
                perfect++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("there are %i perfect numbers", perfect);
}
```

The problem I traced is this, but I am confused about it? What's wrong?

```
                    if ( j % array[i] == 0) {
                        perf += j;
                    }
```

Comment: (1) Your `j` loop should start at 1, not 0, and (2) `j % array[i] == 0` should be `array[i] % j == 0`

Comment: Oh, what a silly mistake that I did ;-; . Thank you!